# How do I express $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{k=1} \dfrac{6}{n}\sqrt{11 - \dfrac{6k}{n}}$ as a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to interpret
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{k=1} 6\sqrt{\frac{11}{n^2} - \frac{6k}{n^3}}
$$
as a definite integral.

I managed to convert it in the form of
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{6}{n}\sqrt{11 - \frac{6k}{n}}
$$
but am now stuck.

I do understand that the interval length is 6 units, and that the width of each rectangle (i.e., $\Delta{x}$) is $\dfrac{6}{n}$.

What I am struggling with is identifying the lower and upper limits. I initially thought that $a = 11$ was supposed to be the lower limit, however that just does not make sense, because as $k$ increases $x$ is just decreasing.

So is $a = 11$ supposed to be the upper limit, and $b = 11 - 6$ the lower one?

Any help or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can see $6$ as $6-0$, and hence your limit equals $\int_0^6 \sqrt{11-x}\text{d}x$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: There must be some typo, your integrand is not real over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Bernkastel Yes, and obviously it should be $11-6x$ *instead of* $1-6x$.

Comment: @Bernkastel Thanks for the response. May I know how you're able to choose the lower and upper limits as 0 and 6 respectively? Is it just by definition?

Comment: @Bernkastel Yes of course, I meant $$\int_0^1 6 \sqrt{11-6x} dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $6$ is a constant factor, we may consider  $\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{11 - \frac{6k}{n}}$ and multiply by $6$ in the last step. The length of each small interval is $\frac{1}{n}$, and the interval on which we do the integration has length $n\cdot\frac{1}{n}=1$, so we may select the interval to be $[0, 1]$.

(In fact an integration on any interval $[a, b]$ ($a\ne b$) can be transformed to an integration on $[0, 1]$, by a linear transformation of variable that send $[a, b]$ to $[0, 1]$).

Now we may want $f(\frac{i}{n})=\sqrt{11 - \frac{6i}{n}}$, $1\le i\le n$. $\sqrt{11 - \frac{6i}{n}}$ is already "a function of $\frac{i}{n}$", so it is easy to see $f(x)=\sqrt{11-6x}$ is an appropriate function.

Conclusion: The integral desired is $6\int_0^1 \sqrt{11-6x}dx$.

Comment: Thank you! I've selected the answer.